# how to ignore Minutes and date and time field and only take yyy/mm/dd/hh and count the records that shares the same date and time (hour only)

Tags: sql, sql-server

in the following table I'm trying to compare it to itself by using self join to be able to count TestOrderItemID that share the same createdate excluding minutes and seconds

[image]

for example it should count the createdate that shares the same Year/Month/Day/Hour while ignoring the minutes and seconds, the outcome should be like

[image]

for the first two record with TestOrderItemID 1 and 2 the count_Oftest_sameDate should equal 2 since we will ignore the seconds and minutes ,
also for the last 3 records 16 and 17 and 5 the count_Oftest_sameDate equals 3 since it ignored the minutes and only took hour into consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct date with the YYYY-MM-DD-HH portion and use it in partitioning.

```
SELECT Id
    , COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CreateDate), CAST(CAST([CreateDate] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) ORDER BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CreateDate), CAST(CAST([CreateDate] AS DATE) AS DATETIME))) AS count_Oftest_sameDate
    , CreateDate
FROM Test
ORDER BY CreateDate;
```

This will create the following output -

```
| Id | count_Oftest_sameDate | CreateDate          |
|----|-----------------------|---------------------|
| 1  | 2                     | 15.06.2015 09:42:45 |
| 2  | 2                     | 15.06.2015 09:42:49 |
| 15 | 3                     | 15.06.2015 11:13:40 |
| 13 | 3                     | 15.06.2015 11:13:40 |
| 14 | 3                     | 15.06.2015 11:13:40 |
| 16 | 3                     | 15.06.2015 15:29:29 |
| 17 | 3                     | 15.06.2015 15:29:29 |
| 5  | 3                     | 15.06.2015 15:39:17 |
```

**Update:**

To show only the count for each individual hour the following query could be used

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_Oftest_sameDate
    , DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CreateDate), CAST(CAST([CreateDate] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS [Hour] --, MIN(CreateDate)
FROM Test
GROUP BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CreateDate), CAST(CAST([CreateDate] AS DATE) AS DATETIME));
```

This query will produce the following output -

```
| count_Oftest_sameDate | Hour                |
|-----------------------|---------------------|
| 2                     | 15.06.2015 09:00:00 |
| 3                     | 15.06.2015 11:00:00 |
| 3                     | 15.06.2015 15:00:00 |
```

Comment: thank you for your help, is there a way to use group by , for example for the first two records that share the same date and hour , so in CreatDate (15.06.2015 09:42:45 and 15.06.2015 09:42:49 )   it will be grouped by the year, month,day,hour , therefore the count_Oftest_sameDate  will show number 2 only once also we will exclude the ID column

Comment: You could do that by putting the YYYYMMDDHH portion in the group by clause. please see the update. Please upvote/accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window funcction:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by cast(createdate as date)) as count_of_same_date
from t;
```

Comment: Will it only take the date without the hour?

Comment: @Shahadg . . . Yes, that is how the `date` data type works in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HOUR,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),GETDATE()),CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

In the expression, replace getdate with the datefield you want to perform the calculation on.  This will remove the minutes and seconds, but will keep the hours.

```
2018-01-23 06:55:47.720
```

becomes

```
2018-01-23 06:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ignore part of date you can use the next trick to get data between 2021-08-01 03:06 and 2021-08-01 03:07

```
select * from log.barcode_parsing_log where log_date::text like '2021-08-01 03:06%' or log_date::text like '2021-08-01 03:07%' order by log_date asc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `convert` function , select part of `datetime` string to select row count, here is sample output

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (Testorderitemid INT, Count_offtest_samedate INT, createddate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @mytable
--
SELECT 1, 1, DATEADD(HH, - 4, getdate())

UNION

SELECT 2, 1, DATEADD(second, 10, DATEADD(HH, - 4, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 15, 3, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 3, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 13, 3, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 3, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 14, 3, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 3, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 16, 2, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 1, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 16, 2, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 1, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 17, 2, dateadd(MINUTE, - 35, DATEADD(HH, - 1, getdate()))

UNION

SELECT 5, 1, dateadd(MINUTE, - 15, DATEADD(HH, - 1, getdate()))

SELECT Testorderitemid, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY convert(VARCHAR(13), createddate, 120)) AS Same_hour_count, createddate
FROM @mytable t;
```

Comment: -1 Combining rows of distinct values should use Union All rather than Union.
Converting a date to a string can cause a significant decrease in performance as any indexes on the date column are ignored.

Comment: @wes h OP needs output of query, its just a sample data from table variable . Thanks anyways :)